# What is the benefits to create Google "How to do " videos to the ordinary YouTube videos?

Tags: action, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

Is there some benefits of the ranging video in youtube or in search?

I attended the Google I/O conference this year and discovered new future for the Google Assistance the "How to do" guide. I created this video and waiting for the Google to approve it. But I am curious of the benefits for this type videos for the people who creating the content.

"Google how to video content"

Comment: I mean Youtube how-to videos: https://www.cnet.com/news/from-google-io-youtube-how-to-videos-are-about-to-get-way-more-useful/

Comment: What do you mean by "ranging video"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: By "ranging the video" I mean that video will have more priority while searching for the video in youtube or google for example.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest advantage is that these videos will be surfaced through the Assistant on devices that have video capabilities and users will be able to go through them step by step through voice commands. So they won't need to explicitly stop and start a video (possibly while their hands are full) - the video will pause at that point and wait for them to prompt to continue.

Comment: Thank you for the informative explanation. Would these videos have priorities in the google search result list while searching for something using Google Assistant?